# JavaScript "Packed" Function in CSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I have an obfuscated `(p,a,c,k,e,d)` function from JavaScript.

```
string value = @"eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d)
            {while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+c.toString(a)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);
            return p}
('3("3b").3a({39:\"5://1b.1a.19.8:18/38/v.37\",36:\"5://1b.1a.19.8:18/i/35/34/33.32\",31:\"\",30:\"2z\",2y:\"2x\",2w:2v,2u:\"7\",2t:\"2s\",2r:[],2q:{2p:\'#2o\',2n:22,2m:\"2l\",2k:0}});b f;b k=0;b 6=0;3().2j(2(x){a(6>0)k+=x.17-6;6=x.17;a(0!=0&&k>=0){6=-1;3().2i();3().2h(2g);$(\'#2f\').j();$(\'h.g\').j()}});3().2e(2(x){6=-1});3().2d(2(x){16(x)});3().2c(2(){$(\'h.g\').j()});2 16(x){$(\'h.g\').2b();a(f)2a;f=1;$.29(\'5://12.9/15-28/27.15?26=25&24=23&21=20-1z-1y-1x-1w\',2(14){$(\'#1v\').1u(14)})};3().1t(\'1s\',2(){b 13=3().1r();13.1q(\'1p\',2(){11.10(\'z-y\')[0].w[1].1o=\"5://12.9\";11.10(\'z-y\')[0].w[1].1n=\"<u>1m - 1l 1k 1j & 1i</u>\"});a($.c(\'4\')==\"d\"){t.s(\"5://r.q.p/o/7.n\",\"m 9 1h\",e,\"l\")}1g{t.s(\"5://r.q.p/o/d.n\",\"m 9 1f\",e,\"l\")}});2 e(){$.c(\'4\')==\'7\'?4=\'d\':4=\'7\';$.c(\'4\',4);1e.1d.1c()};',36,120,'||function|jwplayer|primaryCookie|http|p02887336|html5||to|if|var|cookie|flash|switchMode|vvplay|video_ad|div||show|tt2887336|button2|Switch|png|images|tv|flashx|static|addButton|this|center||childNodes||featured|jw|getElementsByClassName|document|streamin|container|data|cgi|doPlay|position|8777|213|211|95|reload|location|window|Flash|else|HTML5|Storage|Sharing|Video|Free|Streamin|innerHTML|href|contextmenu|addEventListener|getContainer|ready|on|html|fviews|fb98c55a544241de2464a88086a6b0c9|1486917733|186|182|2887336|hash||2ca0tpqawtre|file_code|view|op|index_dl|bin|get|return|hide|onComplete|onPlay|onSeek|play_limit_box|false|setFullscreen|stop|onTime|backgroundOpacity|Arial|fontFamily|fontSize|FFFFFF|color|captions|tracks|start|startparam|primary|326|height|580|width|2638|duration|skin|jpg|lhl2j9yhfp1s|00085|01|image|mp4|rwi7bsgc5huzcg3h5fpsfen3362uwfp4cyzyo2mavczsvbbx4tnesmwhdteq|file|setup|vplayer'.split('|')))"
```

I am trying to use `jint` to interpret and get the value of the above `function` but when I execute the statement in `jint engine` it throws an exception for `jwplayer is not defined`.

I know why the exception is thrown but I only want to get the value of `p` above. But `jint` runs the whole function and then ends up with an empty function which doesn't exist and when it tries to run it, an exception is thrown.

I only want it to return the value in a string and it should not run it any further. I have already tried to search it for an answer but so far found nothing.
I am using the code as following:

```
 Jint.Engine jEngine = new Jint.Engine();
 var linkString = jEngine.Execute(value).GetCompletionValue().ToString();
 var arrayFile = linkString.Split(' ', '\n');
```

Is something I am missing here? If someone can shed some light on it. That will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Firstly, that's not valid C# code you have posted, looks like you haven't correctly escaped the double quotes. Secondly, the error is probably because your obfuscated function is trying to call a method or an object called `jwplayer` (which appears to be an embedded video player)

Comment: I know it is a method/object but how can I make sure that `jint` doesn't call it in the end? I only need the return value generated in the main function.

Comment: Well you can see that from looking at it, that it returns `p` which is the first parameter which is the first string parameter passed in to it.

Comment: I know that, I need the return value as a `string` but the `jint` tries to execute that returned value which causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was `eval` at the start of the packed function. It was running the code after getting the value. So I removed the `eval` part and now it works as expected.